# Back button Working on local but failed on live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am trying to prevent back/forward button in browser but not getting success! any help is appreciated...

The following code working on my local system but not on server.

```
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
   history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
});
```

Comment: did you get any error? check console and let us know

Comment: no there is no error showing in console..

Answer (score 0):

try warning user rather then preventing because not every browser supports this

use following code to warn user

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    return "Are you sure ? work will be lost."; 
};
```

Comment: This is not the same thing as the navigation buttons. This won't fire if the last entry in history is a hash location on the current document.